# CIDetector RectOfInterest

Tags: ios, swift, cidetector

What I need todo is make a Scanner to scan the documents. Currently I am using `CIDetector` to detect any rectangle using type `CIDetectorTypeRectangle`

```
func detectRectangleInScanner() -> CIDetector {

    let options: [String: AnyObject] = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]
    return CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeRectangle, context: nil, options: options)

}
```

It's working fine and detecting the rectangles with edges.

Now I have made a scanner-view overlay with the four corners such that if the document lies within those overlay frame then only the scanner will detect that document. [Video Link](http://sendvid.com/n13694lm)

`AVCaptureMetadataOutput` has a property `rectOfInterest` that does the same thing, but unfortunately it can't be used for document scanning.

Comment: AVCaptureMetadataOutput's rectOfInterest doesn't detect rectangles. It's just the region to search for metadata (face, qrcode).

Comment: Yes, I know that. My question is how can we get the same thing using `AVFoundation` and `CIDetector`? See the video link